# Firefox. TypeError: 0 is read-only

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firefox

I'm experiencing this error only in Firefox.
Can't find a root of the problem.
Stack trace refers to node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
The end point is this line inside jquery
`style[ name ] = value;` in style method of jquery but there is no style method calls in my app code.
Maybe old Angular.js calls it in `ng-style` evaluation?
Any suggestion are appreciated.

Angular 1.6
Angular 5.2.9 (hybrid app)
JQuery 3.3.1 (yeah, I know it's ugly, we are going to get rid of it in new Angular version of our app)
Firefox 60.0.1

**UPD** Error log.

> TypeError: 0 is read-only Stack trace:
>   style@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:6498:6
>   set@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:6764:5
>   run@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:6725:4
>   tick@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:7094:5
>   jQuery.fx.tick@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:7436:9
>   schedule@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:6813:3
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17
>   onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4956:24
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17
>   Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28
>   ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:24
>   ZoneTask/this.invoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:485:28
>   timer@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2025:17

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only

Comment: @JaromandaX Have read it already. Doesn't helps a little since our project is very big and I don't know what code caused the error  
There are no defineProperty or freeze in my code either. So It should be some global property, something like that.

Comment: we can't see your project at all - so, you have a better chance :p

Comment: you need to post your entire error log, if we can't see it, we can't help

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Added an error log. Can't post any code because the project is very large and the issue is that I don't know which module is causing an error.

Comment: are you bundling your modules? This is some kind of string-immutability bug that, perhaps, happens with conflicting libraries

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yeah, I'm using webpack.  I think it's not a string immutability error but issue with trying to set to unexisted or protected  property of CSS2Properties style object.  In debugger mode I checked the value on `name` variable. It's actually a zero digit string ("0")

Comment: I think I found a culprit. I'll describe it a little bit latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging in Mozilla web inspector I found out which element style was affected by jquery style method.
It was some legacy code which had to remove element after the end of transition.

```
$('.digit')
.css({ transform: 'translateY(2.5em)' })
.animate('slow', () => { $('.digit').remove(); });
```

As you can see animate method was called without css properties object defined.
Don't know what version of JQuery have allowed such a syntax but I solved the bug changing code like that

```
const $digit = $('.digit');
$digit.css({ transform: 'translateY(2.5em)' });
$digit.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', () => {
    $digit.remove();
});
```